# How do I use a function to remove apostrophes from a string in python?

Tags: python

I need to make a function remove_apos() function, which has a string as a parameter, and returns a string with any apostrophes removed.in the string. These should be removed so that only the letters in a word are counted. For example, the word "NASA's" should be treated as "NASAs" and would have a length of 5. The aimed output of my function is:

```
Enter name of file:
cassini.txt
File to be processed is:  cassini.txt
The number of words is:    231
The average length of a word is:   5.34
```

My code so far:

```
# Define your functions here

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Prompt the user for the name of the file and open it for reading
    input = input('Enter name of file:\n')
    print('File to be processed is: {}'.format(input))

    # Open the file for reading here

    my_file = open(input) 

    line = my_file.read()
    words = line.split()

    add = 0
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        word_wo_punc = "".join([x for x in word if x.isalpha() or x in ("-")])
        add = add + len(word_wo_punc)
        if len(word_wo_punc) > 0:
            count = count + 1
    avg = add/count


    print('The number of words is: {}'.format(count))
    print('The average length of a word is: {:.2f}'.format(avg))
```

I tried to put this part in a function:

```
add = 0
count = 0
for word in words:
    word_wo_punc = "".join([x for x in word if x.isalpha() or x in ("-")])
    add = add + len(word_wo_punc)
    if len(word_wo_punc) > 0:
        count = count + 1
avg = add/count
```

But nothing seemed to work or I can't figure out how to return word_wo_punc properly. I was wondering how to remove apostrophes from a string in python, and how to encode this in a function so that I can call it?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expression ? Something like should help you remove special characters. `s = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", s)`

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service, but we can help you debug code you write. Please post your best attempt. See [mre] for reference. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: Your requirements are inconsistent. First you say the function "returns a string with any apostrophes removed" then you say "The aimed output of my function is:" with some stats about the file. Which one do you actually need help with? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Do you know about https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 0):

Without any dependencies, uses `str.replace`:

```py
txt = "NASA's"
print(txt.replace("'", ""))
```

output: `NASAs`

Answer (score 0):

To wrap the section of code in a function, declare it before `if __name__=="__main""`, i.e.

```py
def process_text_original(text_input):
    add = 0
    count = 0
    for word in text_input:
        word_wo_punc = "".join([x for x in word if x.isalpha() or x in ("-")])
        add = add + len(word_wo_punc)
        if len(word_wo_punc) > 0:
            count = count + 1
    avg = add/count

    return count, avg

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Prompt the user for the name of the file and open it for reading
    input = input('Enter name of file:\n')
    print('File to be processed is: {}'.format(input))

    # Open the file for reading here

    my_file = open(input) 

    line = my_file.read()
    words = line.split()

    count, avg = process_text_original(words)

    print('The number of words is: {}'.format(count))
    print('The average length of a word is: {:.2f}'.format(avg))
```

Regarding testing your function to ensure it's doing what you want, you could declare a second function

```
def word_wo_punc_func(word):
    return "".join([x for x in word if x.isalpha() or x in ("-")])
```

and call it like

```
def process_text(text_input):
    add = 0
    count = 0
    for word in text_input:
        word_wo_punc = word_wo_punc_func(word)
        add = add + len(word_wo_punc)
        if len(word_wo_punc) > 0:
            count = count + 1
    avg = add/count

    return count, avg
```

Note that the order in which you declare the function matters -- you have to declare functions before you call them, so your whole script would look like

```
def word_wo_punc_func(word):
    ...
def process_text(text_input):
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

The great thing about breaking the code apart into functions is that you can test it interactively. Say that script is called something like "clean_text.py", you can then start an interactive session by calling `python` (without any argument)

```
from clean_text import word_wo_punc_func
word_wo_punc_func("NASA's")
>>>'NASAs'
```

where the module name must match the filename of your script. According to my test, your code already removes apostrophes correctly.